# Running SQL View from two different SQL Server Management Studio Servers on Production taking different time

Tags: sql, ssms, sql-server-2016

We have two SQL Server machines in production:

1. SQL_Server_1
2. SQL_Server_2

We have a view on `SQL_Server_1`. If we select from that view from `SQL_Server_2` SSMS, then it takes around 6 seconds to retunr. But the same view executed from SQL_Server_1 SSMS, then it is taking more than 10 minutes. View has only join of 3 tables.

Here I am not able to understand how query is taking so much of time if we execute it from same server where it is resides.

Please help me out here.

Comment: You need to provide more information about what the view does.  It sounds like you have cross-database stuff going one.

Comment: You don't **execute** views - you **select from views** (since they're almost like tables). You can execute functions or procedures

Comment: Yes,we have two different database servers.Basically view is used to pass data to application. Application take data from two SQL server does further operations.

Comment: Yes,@marc_s you are right. We are selecting from view like select * from view_name.

Comment: I think it is not related to view,we checked form activity monitor of SQL Server 1 on that it is showing 60 to 80 % utilization and same for SQL Server 2 is 30 to 40%. So I think it is related to memory.

Comment: performance may be affected due to the load on the server.